# Hybrid hibernate on Ubuntu?

Tags: startup, hibernate

After I saw Windows 8 uses hybrid hibernation instead of shutdown by default in order to solve its slow startup issue, I want to know if it's possible to use **hybrid hibernation** on Ubuntu to speed up its *fast* startup?

If yes, how? And does it really affect the startup time – for example 30 sec to 10 sec?

Comment: That's a very good question, I'm a big fan of Hybrid Sleep on Windows 7 myself. Hadn't even crossed my mind if it was possible in Ubuntu.

Comment: Add me to the list of interested in this!

Comment: It seems not to be an issue of interest on Ubuntu because of swap problems with an encrypted installation.